# Проектирование БД столовой

Tags: sql, база-данных, проектирование

Добрый день. Делаю бд маленькой столовой. Мне кажется, что у меня не совсем правильно с логической стороны построена модель. Что можете сказать? Что убрать а что добавить?

Человек приходит и набирает еду. У одного человека один заказ,в котором множество блюд. Т.е. каждый день один заказ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы сказать, что именно не так в схеме, необходимо описание предметной области. Сущности, ограничения, примеры запросов. Небольшое замечание: ключевое поле у сущности `Food` стоит назвать `id`. Кроме того, я бы не ставил `Order` таблицей-связкой между человеком и едой (поскольку тогда у каждого человека будет один заказ, сколько бы еды он не запросил), а выделил бы `Order` в отдельную сущность, связав ее М2М c `Food`.

Comment: А зачем в таблице `Food` есть поле `id_order`? Оно там точно лишнее. И еда может быть только в одной категории?

Comment: Да. еда может быть только в одной категории. В одном заказе множество блюд.

Answer (score 3):

1. Я бы сменил именование идентификаторов вместо id_people писал бы people_id. Читая  модели других БД Вы сами поймете, что это
2. Смотря на табличку мне не сразу удалось разглядеть, что order это связь многие-ко-многим. Потому что не явно выражено что id_people это внешний ключ на people.id
3. С какой целью существует поле food.id_order ? Ведь у Вас в Order уже есть поле id_food. Этого более чем достаточно!
4. Компоненты в блюде будете хранить? К примеру некоторые девушки в кафе начинают мучать себя вопросами вида "Насколько калорийное данное блюдо?" ответить на который можно или указать общее поле 'калории' , либо завести список компонентов и на каждый указать "калории" и вычислять в процессе работы
5. Могу ли я как покупатель блюда исключить какие-то ингредиенты? К примеру очень бесит когда в оливье суют яблоки, убил бы! ;)))

Answer (score 1):

Имеется подобная база данных на SQLite

[image: скриншот]

[image: Схема БД]

приложит ссылку на программу увы не могу, не хватает репутации.

Comment: Скиньте плиз ссылку)

Comment: Спасибо за репутацию, ссылка: https://www.dropbox.com/s/thtnq9v3zatempp/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F.zip?dl=0

Comment: Спасибо за программу сделанную в конструкторе)!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы советовал следовать общему принципу логического именования таблиц. Во множественном числе. Например вот так:

**Сustomers** - условно, *едоки*. Пожалуйста, не надо *people*. В этом слове намного больше абстракции, чем вы можете себе представить ;)

**Orders** - заказы, чеки. Тут все должно быть понятно.

**Meals** - Блюда. Это более подходящее слово, нежели *food*.

**MealCategories** - категории блюд. То есть мы соблюдаем множественное число (categor**ies**) и в то же время показываем, что категории относятся именно к блюдам.

Comment: Ну сделали бы еще один заказ) в чем траблы

Comment: Да, конечно же. Многие-ко-многим не нужно. Это я невнимательно посмотрел)) Ща поправлю.

Comment: Просто в вопросе немного смущает *"...Т.е. каждый день один заказ."*